# Bind parent $scope to ng-repeat in elements created on demand

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

So, I'm trying to create a Collection obj(model) that has multiple subcollections (and each subcollection has other subcollections) and they have to be added on demand (click of a button).

My current code is:

HTML:

```
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="addSubCol()">ADD SUBCOL</button>
<div ng-repeat="subcollection in collection.subcollections">
    <input type="text" value="{{subcollection.name}}">
    <span>COLLECTION OBJ SUBCOL TITLE: {{collection.subcollections[$index].name}}</span>
</div>
</div>
```

and JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function mainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.collection = {};
    $scope.collection.subcollections = [{name:'TEST1'}];

    $scope.addSubCol = function(){
        var subcollection = {
            name: 'TEST',
            otherSubCol: []
        }
        $scope.collection.subcollections.push(subcollection);
    };
}
```

This fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/xznjs/2/) show the issue at hand. The expected result is that the new subcollection created on demand gets binded to the parent collection.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your input to use the `ng-model` attribute. Like so

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="subcollection.name">
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xznjs/6/)

Comment: Yeah, and you don't need all the craziness. Just say ng-model='subcollection'. And same thing for the span {{subcollection.name}}

Comment: It works on the Fiddle! But I tried it on my project and the $index portion is not getting evaluated but I don't see why...any pointers?

Comment: Oh and using only subcollection.name doesn't seem to be working.